# Azure APIM - tracing and troubleshooting?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have deployed my application on Azure kubernetes and I am using APIM to expose THE API services.

I want to trace the incoming requests to understand the complete execution. Eg: how long it takes to process the request by the APIM.

Is there any way to trace the individual request in azure APIM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use *Products* in Azure API Management, there's an *administrator* subscription key, that allows you to monitor every step executed in APIM.

Please check the following link to get more detailed information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-api-inspector

Basically, you have to add this subscription-key and also add an *Ocp-Apim-Trace: true* header to receive the *Ocp-Apim-Trace-Location* header, which is a link to a *json* file containing each executed step.